# Nested configuration property with same tag name in C#

Tags: c#, xml, configuration

I am trying to implement the following Configuration Reading one of the config file in C#.

```
<node name = "abc">
  <node name = "test1"/>
</node>
<node name = "test">
  <node name = "test1"/>
</node>
<node name = "test3">
  <node name = "test1"/>
</node>
```

Here my purpose is to iterate over the child recursively and generate a dictionary.

I added a configuration file shown as the following snippet.

But I am getting the following error saying the attribute "name" has been locked in higher level configuration. Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue.

Found that the lockproperty is set to true while iterating this configuration

Code Snippet

```
  [ConfigurationProperty("name", DefaultValue = "", IsKey = true, IsRequired 
 = true)]
public string name {
 get { return (string)base["name"]; }
 set { base["name"] = value; }
}

[ConfigurationProperty("node", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
public NodeCollection Statuses {
 get { return (NodeCollection)base["node"]; }
}
```